# Comparing x and y coordinates and eliminating the elements from a list of list of tuples

Tags: python, list, iteration, tuples

I have a **list 'u' containing a set of lists that inorder contains tuples (x,y)**. As a part of a bigger problem, I got a list and I am trying to compare each tuple element in a list of tuples with elements in other list of tuples in the list 'u' in such a way that: **I need to compare an element for example: (3,10) belonging to u[0] list will be compared against elements with same x co-ordinate in the list u[1], u[2], u[3]... and as the X co-ordinates are equal, the elements that contain the highest y co-ordinate survives in their lists but the one with smallest y co-ordinate should be eliminated.**

```
u = [[(2, 10), (3, 10), (4, 10), (5, 10), (6, 10), (7, 10), (8, 10), (9, 10)],
 [(3, 15), (4, 15), (5, 15), (6, 15), (7, 15)],
 [(5, 12), (6, 12), (7, 12), (8, 12), (9, 12), (10, 12), (11, 12), (12, 12)],
 [(15, 10), (16, 10), (17, 10), (18, 10), (19, 10), (20, 10)],
 [(19, 8), (20, 8), (21, 8), (22, 8), (23, 8), (24, 8)]]

(3,10) of u[0] compared against (3,15) of u[1] => (3,15) survives and (3,10) gets eliminated from the list.
```

So, I hope someone can help me with a simpler and more **pythonic solution** for this. Thanks in advance

Here's what I have done:

```
def filterAllmax(self, u):
        u = [item for sub in u for item in sub]
        for i in range(len(u)):
            for j in range(i, len(u)):
                for k in u[i]:
                    if k[0][0] in u[j]:
                        m += [u[i] for i, v in enumerate(u[j]) if v[1] < k[0][1] # store the values that have y co-ordinates less than the value
        for i in m:
            u.remove(i)
        return u
```

> Note: Prior to posting my query, I have searched the stackoverflow for
>   relevant solutions, but I couldn't find the one that fits my needs.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: This isn't a code-snippet site, so I'm not surprised that you didn't find an existing snippet for this specific task.

Comment: Well I know that this is not a code-snippet site. And I have been looking for an approach to compare the tuples in a list of lists. I don't need the exact solution. I just need an approach for this. I will post what I have tried so far.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I have added what I have tried for the problem. Can you help me with the solution now? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write a Pythonic way.

```
print {i1[0]: max(0,*(i[1] for i in sum(u, []) if i[0] == i1[0])) for i1 in sum(u, [])}
```

Result:

```
{2: 10, 3: 15, 4: 15, 5: 15, 6: 15, 7: 15, 8: 12, 9: 12, 10: 12, 11: 12, 12: 12, 15: 10, 16: 10, 17: 10, 18: 10, 19: 10, 20: 10, 21: 8, 22: 8, 23: 8, 24: 8}
```

`sum(u, [])` converts the nested list to a flat list:

```
[(2, 10), (3, 10), (4, 10), (5, 10), (6, 10), (7, 10), (8, 10), (9, 10), (3, 15), (4, 15), (5, 15), (6, 15), (7, 15), (5, 12), (6, 12), (7, 12), (8, 12), (9, 12), (10, 12), (11, 12), (12, 12), (15, 10), (16, 10), (17, 10), (18, 10), (19, 10), (20, 10), (19, 8), (20, 8), (21, 8), (22, 8), (23, 8), (24, 8)]
```

Then iterate the list,use `max()` to get the maximum value and use a dict comprehension to return the result.